# Was "Jose Chung's From Outer Space" based on a real book?

Tags: books, the-x-files

One of my favorite TV episodes of any show of all time was XFiles Season 3 **[Jose Chung's From Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jose_Chung%27s_From_Outer_Space)**. Is the book from said episode based on a real book?

Comment: Can this question just be modified to to ask "was the book from this episode based on a real book"? It's a much better question, with a good answer, than half the questions on this site.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - That question would be firmly on-topic.

Comment: Done, queue the re-opening. Congratulations @Nichaolas, you have my first re-open vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cover and some of the content loosely referenced a 'non-fiction' book titled "**[Communion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communion_(book))**" by Whitley Strieber.

> **Communion**: A True Story is a book by American ufologist and horror
>   author Whitley Strieber that was first published in February 1987. The
>   book is based on the claims of Whitley Strieber, who experiences "lost
>   time" and terrifying flashbacks, which hypnosis undertaken by Budd
>   Hopkins later links to an alleged encounter with aliens.

[image]

Comment: what was wrong w/ my answer?

Comment: Well, the question seems to be a list/recommendation type question. The general rule of thumb is that when things are on their way to being closed for being off-topic, answering them is not appropriate behaviour as it encourages off-topic questions. Per the FAQ "*Not all questions can or should be answered here*"

Comment: @NKCampbell   Good call, and thanks for risking the wrath of the hard working curators.

Comment: Ah - thanks, @Valorum. I didn't see it as a list question (since Communion immediately came to mind) and since it wasn't closed yet, thus being open, it was answerable. Only two votes to close had occurred so clearly it wasn't a slam dunk close at the time I answered it. There was no comment as to why there were votes (which is entirely unhelpful to a low rep user asking a question as well as for people unfamiliar with general rules of thumb. If a question should be closed it should be closed, if it remains open, it can be answered imo. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: This question just had some list *buzzwords* in it, which I removed. Now it fits the mold.

Comment: @NKCampbell - The grey area is when a post is on its way to being closed. Two close votes in less than 5 minutes is a pretty good indication that that's about to happen.

Comment: @NKCampbell - The close vote script offers some useful advice why the question was closed. Adding comments isn't really necessary when the close reason is close to being textbook.

Comment: @Valorum NKCampbell knew the answer to the on-topic version of this question, so he answered it. His answer gave perspective to the rest of us to know that there was an on-topic question this could change into. I'm staunchly against forced down-vote explanations, but I think this answer was a positive contribution, definitely not downvote worthy. Also, "list" questions aren't list questions if they are answerable with a reasonably small (in this case 1-item) list. I've seen plenty of terrible "list" questions stave off closing because someone insists the question is answerable.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - I don't disagree. In its new format, the question is both answerable and on-topic. In its original format, it was speculative and off-topic.